# Simple Map not showing

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a very simple Map defined like this:

```
var _mapOptions = {
   zoom: 15,
   center: new google.maps.LatLng(-22.9965949, -43.2710887),
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var _mapCtl = document.getElementById("map-control");
var _map = new google.maps.Map(_mapCtl, _mapOptions);
```

The html "map-control" is defined in a div like this:

```
<div id="map-view" class="view" style="display: none">
    <div id="map-control" style="width:100%; height=100%"></div>
</div>
```

The div is loaded dinamically with jquery and is initially invisible. Debugging I have verified that `document.getElementById("map-control");` retuns an html element and sets `_mapCtl`.

To complete I am loading google apis like this:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey&sensor=false"></script>
```

What could this be ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `style="display: none"` do you have css that hide the map?

Comment: There may be hundreds of similiar questions here that will tell you that you have to trigger the resize -event when you show the div and that you have to define a proper size for the div(100% of 0 is still 0)...does this question have to be answered every day again.

Comment: Furthermore: `height=100%` is invalid CSS

Comment: I found it, I had to define width and height explicitly. width:250px; height=250px. And it worked. Thanks